# android can not get child view inside recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I try to get childView by position.I wrote something like this code

```
private void showDirectDebitShadow(int pos, String message) {
    boolean allowScale = false;
    if (pos > 0 && isRecyclerScrollable()) {
        templateList.getRecyclerView().post(() -> layoutManager.scrollToPosition(pos));
    }
    if (pos < layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()) {
        allowScale = false;
    } else {
        allowScale = true;
    }
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        templateList.getRecyclerView().post(() -> {
            View childView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos);
            if (childView != null) {
                childView.postDelayed(() -> {
                    SwipeMenuLayout swipeMenuLayout = childView.findViewById(R.id.SwipeMenuLayout);
                    View directDebitIcon = childView.findViewById(R.id.direct_debit_icon);
                    if (swipeMenuLayout != null && directDebitIcon != null) {
                        swipeMenuLayout.smoothExpand();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> showCaseView(message, directDebitIcon, getActivity(), swipeMenuLayout), 400);

                    }
                },500);

            }
        });
    }, isRecyclerScrollable() ? 500 : 100);
}
```

I debugged it and my child view isn't null but I can get another views (SwipeMenuLayout and directDebitIcon) from childView
Can anyone tell me what's a wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

use `reyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` to be able to access `ViewHolder` and then you can get any child view through it easily